# CP2102N-QFN20 Overheats and Blows Board

Tags: power-supply, usb, uart

I'm currently working with a custom board that uses the CP2102N-QFN20 connected to a USB-C female port and an MCU for UART. The device should be bus powered, and as far as I can tell, I've followed the datasheet recommendations to the letter, but when I plug any of the custom boards in, the CP2102N overheats and blows the board.

I've tried plugging in to both USB power supply and directly into a PC. Before blowing the board, I managed to check the voltage on the VBUS coming into the IC, and it's reading at 5V. There seems to be no 3.3V output though.

The board is 4 layer with dedicated 3v3 Power Plane and Ground Plane. Attached are schematics and some screenshots of the board layout highlighting the VBUS (5V) and 3v3 lines around the CP2102N.

I've obviously missed something, but if anyone can give any pointers on what the issue could be, that would be great.

[image: 3v3]

[image: VBUS 5V]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: No 3V3 out and overheating; Did you double check that the 3V3 is not shorted somewhere? Also, those LED's without current limiting resistors doesn't look very good.

Comment: Oh that's an error in the schematic. There are 220R resistors between the LED and the 3v3.

I'm going to go through and make certain that 3v3 isn't shorted somewhere but the design rules on the board are pretty strict so it should have picked up unless it's a manufacturing error.

Comment: Since there are resistors missing in the schematics but are actually present in the design, how can we be sure that anything else we are seeing in the schematics is true? If we disregard that, is the component mounted in correct orientation on PCB? Also the design will never work if you connect to a laptop Type-C port, the laptop cannot even detect that anything is connected and won't output 5V. It will only work on a laptop Type-A port with an adapter cable. You can't change an older USB receptacle to Type-C and expect it to work without designing the change to Type-C connector correctly.

Comment: I'm going to review the schematic and update as soon as possible to make sure everything does match.

Regarding using USB-C, it was a C to A adapter going into the PC and I've also tried C to C. We've got another device that works fine using this method, but the IC is an FTDI FT232. USB-C is backwards compatible with USB-A in that you can still use the VBUS, GND and D+ / D- pins on USB-C to connect to USB-A. The only difference is that there are two of each pin to make it reversible, so the routing for D+ / D- can be a bit tricky.

Comment: @AndyMills Your understanding about USB-C is incorrect. Sure, it's downwards compatible with USB-A but due to your design flaws your design will only work with in USB-A port of your PC, and no standard compliant USB-C will give your device 5V. USB power bricks with captive cable do give always 5V like USB-A to USB-C cables. The differences go way deeper than just having a reversible connector with two sets of USB 2.0 data wires.

Comment: I did use a USB-A port on the PC to connect to the device. I also used a power adapter which was USB-A and used a USB-A to USB-C cable. I did this first and the overheating still happened. Can you explain more about what you mean? If only lines are being used (5v, GND, D+ and D-) from the cable and connector on the board, and I measured that 5v was coming into the device, what else could affect it? Thanks for the help by the way - it's good information to have!

Comment: Why don't you just check with a DMM if there is any short between 3.3V  and GND, and not relying on some "DRC rules"?